# DB sketcher for MacOS?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ddl

I've been trying to find a free database creator for mac os, and i'm not being able to find any. Anyone know of a free one i could download?

EDIT: I need that the application generate the sql (mysql in this case) also :)

ty

Comment: I can't edit posts yet but I would say...

 I need that the application generate the DDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Designer](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/) is web-based.

There's also more options at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474/database-schema-diagram-design-tool).

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Entity modeling stuff in XCode](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650) might be of us to you...

Answer (score 0):

[SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com/) is another web-based one available.