# db documentation

Tags: database, db2

hi is there a good data dictionary tool out there for a db2 database on linux or mac.
Could only find some win apps.
maybe something wiki like or html generator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

druid druid.sourceforge.net is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a tool to create some documentation (data model etc.) for a db2 database and not the db2 documentation?

If so these two questions should help:

[DB sketcher for MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233636/db-sketcher-for-macos)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474/database-schema-diagram-design-tool

If you're after something that will create a "data dictionary"-type document (list and description of tables and columns) then you're right, the best ones I know of (ERWin, ERStudio) are Windows only.

Comment: yes was just looking for a data dictionnary aka erwin...
for schema graphs dbvisualizer is great tool

Comment: Suggestion: edit your question above to indicate that you were looking for a data dictionary tool, then add druid as an answer to your question below, and accept it.  You'll be helping other people who are looking for a data dictionary tool by making the question and answer obvious.